# Webpack exposing static files?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, compression, create-react-app

I've built an app using the https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app.

When I finally ran npm run build, I noticed that by inspecting the page where my app is served, you are able to view all of my original source code (even though the files were originally compressed).

Is this a feature of webpack or chrome? How can I disable this from happening? I do not want other people to be able to inspect my uncompressed code like that. https://puu.sh/BqFC0/912a3d562d.png

Answer (score 3):

This is because webpack is generating source maps by default.
You can simply delete those files from your build directory. or add `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` to your `.env` file.

Comment: Thanks, this was it!